# slider with 3d effect animation in angular 2 or above

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, slider, effect

I want to use slider in my site with angular 8.
I use ngx-bootstrap for create slider and not problem.
but ngx-bootstrap not have 3d effect animation(brick,cube,louvers,...) for show slides(like wowslider.com).
Does have a module for this job?

Answer (score 0):

to solve your issue you can override the CSS used for crossfade transition, no need of addditional module.

Answer (score 0):

ngx-bootstrap slider is just meant as a basic slider to show images. Wowslider is software that generates advanced javascript.

As it is two independant sliders, there is no "module" , unless you make something yourself. However, it looks like wowslider exports to angular, so you don't need ngx-bootstrap at all.